# CvInvoke.Canny() - gives different results on different computers

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, canny-operator

when trying to perform some binary manipulations on the exact same image file, but on different computers (&monitors), i get a different result when using the `CvInvoke.Canny()` method.
before calling this method, i use several manipulating methods such as: `CvInvoke.Threshold()` , `CvInvoke.Erode()` , `CvInvoke.Dilate()` and more...
the result of all of these is always equal.
it is just when i call:

```
UMat inputImageUMAT = new Image<Gray, byte>(inputImageBitmap).ToUMat();
UMat imageUmat = new UMat();
CvInvoke.Threshold(imageInputUMAT, imageUmat, threshold, 255, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ThresholdType.Binary);

// clear noises with Erode & Dilate:
CvInvoke.Erode(imageUmat, imageUmat, null, new Point(-1, -1), 1, 
BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);
CvInvoke.Dilate(imageUmat, imageUmat, null, new Point(-1, -1), 1, 
BorderType.Constant, CvInvoke.MorphologyDefaultBorderValue);

//use image pyr to remove noise:
UMat pyrDown = new UMat();
CvInvoke.PyrDown(imageUmat, pyrDown);
CvInvoke.PyrUp(pyrDown, imageUmat);

 // set cannyEdges to hold the outlines of the shapes detected in the image 
(according to threshold) 
UMat cannyEdges = new UMat();
CvInvoke.Canny(imageUmat, cannyEdges, threshold, threshold);
```

**there is always a difference between the different computers outputs.

nonetheless, every computer always gives the exact same result - time after time.**

what is it that might be causing the problem?
i must have the exact same results everywhere...

p.s.
i use the C# nugget: EMGU.CV v3.3.0.2824

edit:
i took the original file: [original](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7y37xh793ccdt5/andotbadotgray.bmp?dl=0)
and skipped all the manipulations on way and performed `Canny` immediately:

```
UMat inputImageUMAT = new UMat(fileName, ImreadModes.Grayscale);
UMat cannyEdges = new UMat();
CvInvoke.Canny(imageInputUMAT, cannyEdges, threshold, threshold, 3, true);
cannyEdges.Save(outputFileName);
```

result with threshold 210 machine 1: [result_1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5t2i42wwsikea0l/andotbadotgray_threshold_210__canny_comp1.bmp?dl=0)
result with threshold 210 machine 2: [result_2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mt5tf6fkc7sbwiu/andotbadotgray_threshold_210_canny_comp2.bmp?dl=0)
-- there is 1 pixel difference between the 2 results

Comment: when i change the code to: `CvInvoke.Canny(imageUmat, cannyEdges, threshold, threshold, 3 , true);` - there is still difference.

Comment: Can you limit your code to ONLY invoke CvInvoke.Canny on guaranteed same images (no `jpg` compression, only lossless formats) & show us 2 images with diff?

Comment: Also does the output change from one run to another on the same machine too?

Comment: on every machine the results are always the same.

Comment: i'm not sure i understood what u asked for.
    i'm saved the UMAT's to ".bmp" after every step, and compared it by `beyond compare` tool. i don't know how to load the different files - but i'll check this out.

Comment: Different results might be caused by different implementations of decoders. In order to make sure that that is not the case - I recommend to not use any compression for the input files. So simply save your image before invoking `Canny` and feed result into `Canny` on 2 machines, save output as image and put them into your question.

Comment: thanks a lot @DmitriiZ. - i added the files and skipped all compression's on the way - any suggestions for the difference?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. - found it! can't **really** understand wtf - but it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wrote to EMGU's support, and here is their amazing answer:

> I reviewed your code and it is using UMat. That means that the code will using OpenCL (GPU) to speed up the processing when it is available and fall back to CPU for workstation where there is no compatible OpenCL driver / device.
>   My suspicion is that the result produced by the OpenCL path is slightly different from the CPU path. Can you the following line before calling any of the Emgu CV function in your code and check if that make the result consistent across the machines:
>
> `CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = false`
>
> The above code will disable OpenCL and force all the code to run on
>   CPU

not surprisingly - they are right. **it really did solved the issue**.

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I can't say i have understood the reason for the issue by 100%, but i definitely got it stable between all computers.
the thing is that at first i used the static method `CvInvoke.Canny()` and sent the input & output `Umat`'s - it *probably* didn't know for sure what kind of image is the original, and then (by accessing some `windows` dll's or priorities or something?) it led to different decision making on every computer, and therefore the different `Umat` translation led to different results.
(...maybe)

BUT
when i loaded the input image into `Image<Gray, Byte>` and used **its' own** `Canny` method (as well as other methods) - **all is stable with no doubt and no matter what computer it runs on**.
so the working code is:

```
UMat inputImageUMAT = new Image<Gray, byte>(inputFileName).ToUMat();
Image<Gray, Byte> binaryImage = inputImageUMAT.ToImage<Gray,Byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(threshold), new Gray(255));
binaryImage = binaryImage.Erode(1);
binaryImage = binaryImage.Dilate(1);
binaryImage = binaryImage.PyrDown();
binaryImage = binaryImage.PyrUp();
binaryImage = binaryImage.Canny(1, 0, 3, true);
```